# C++ Build an array of data by repeating a vector many times

Tags: c++, performance

I have a sequence of numbers that I need to repeat many times and get the repeated data as a pointer to the data along the size (actually element count). I need that data to pass it on to an API.

What would be the most efficient way to allocate the memory, pass on the repeated data and then free it again. I currently have the sequence that needs to be repeated stored in a std::vector

A couple of thoughts I had were along the lines of:

```
// Setup code
unsigned int repeat = 30000;
std::vector<int> datavector(5, 0); // assume this would contain arbitrary numbers that needed to be repeated

// Idea 1:
{
    unsigned int byte_size_step = datavector.size() * sizeof(int);
    unsigned int byte_full_size = byte_size_step * repeat;
    int *ptr = malloc(byte_full_size);

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<repeat; i++)
    {
        memcpy(ptr+(i*byte_size_step), datavector.data(),  byte_size_step);
    }
    apiFunc(ptr); // apiFunc copies the data
    free(ptr)
}

// Idea 2:
{
    std::vector datarepeated(datavector.size()*repeat);
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<repeat; i++)
    {
        datarepeated.insert(datarepeated.begin()+(i*size_step), datavector.begin(), datavector.end());
    }
    apiFunc(datarepeated.data());
}
```

Though I felt that there would be a function or easy-to-go method laying around to quickly repeat the sequence in memory. I'm probably missing something. I personally don't know if something like this could benefit from a multithreaded solution.

Any tips to do this (most) efficiently are welcome.

Comment: Where is your performance bottleneck? Have you profiled your application? Is it in memory allocation, data copying, elsewhere? Without answers to these question it is not possible to define "most efficient". Until you measure the overall system and find bottleneck I'd say: the less code the better solution. Do not attempt premature optimisation.

Comment: Have you tried `copy(datavector.begin(), datavector.end(), back_inserter(datarepeated));` inside the loop to see how well that performs?

Comment: The standard library likely has optimized range copies for integral types that will either get close, or equal a `memcpy()`, though it would be tough to beat it speed-wise. Another option is to use `reserve()` for the initial target buffer expansion rather than construction-sizing, then appropriate end-insertion. This avoids all the value-initializations of the initial vector.

Answer (score 2):

Both your ideas should have very similar performance. You might, however be able to squeeze a bit more performance out of it by minimizing the number of loop iterations/`memcpy` calls which you can do by *doubling* the length at each iteration. Something like this:

```
// Setup code
const size_t repeat = 10;
int data[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
vector<int> datavec(data, data+5);

// initialize and copy initial segment
vector<int> datarepeated(datavec.size() * repeat);
memcpy(&datarepeated[0], &datavec[0], datavec.size()*sizeof(int));
size_t num_copied = datavec.size();
size_t num_total = datarepeated.size();

// double the amount copied at each iteration
while(num_copied*2 <= num_total) {
    memcpy(&datarepeated[num_copied], &datarepeated[0], num_copied*sizeof(int));
    num_copied *= 2;
}

// copy the final bit
if(num_copied < num_total)
    memcpy(&datarepeated[num_copied], &datarepeated[0], (num_total-num_copied)*sizeof(int));
```

You can see it in action [here](http://codepad.org/mkhSzOBz).

EDIT: Of course, you can try variations on how you do the copying (eg, instead of `memcpy`, use `std::copy` with a `back_inserter` as someone suggested in comments) inside the `while` loop. The key idea I'm trying to express is doing this repeated doubling. Whatever you end up trying, be sure to ***benchmark***.

Comment: How about a statically allocated buffer that is used instead of a malloced one? Dynamic memory allocation is expensive (relatively). If it is really important then how about changing apiFunc() so that it doesn't require repeating data? But I feel that all that is is a premature optimisation. Measure first, optimise later.

Comment: @dmitri Dynamic memory allocation isn't actually *that* slow despite what everyone says. It only becomes an issue if you are doing it in a tight loop (everything you do in a tight loop is a potential issue though). But in this case, there is only one dynamic alloc, and that overhead is going to be minuscule compared to the data replication. Also, static allocation is simply not possible sometimes such as if you don't know the size at compile time, or if you need so much that you might overflow the stack (which could happen in this case depending on compiler).

Comment: That is what I was saying: talk about efficiency doesn't make sense until one has obtained measurements. Until then nothing is slow. Static alloc: you may also alloc a buffer once and if the size is small realloc it doubling the size and so on. That'll reduce number of allocs. etc...

Comment: I don't know if I'm messing something up, but your code seems to be worse than a normal copy-each approach. The only way I'm getting it running a little bit better is with -O0 on this website: https://quick-bench.com/q/PfXBurXnmqY8ej5-9RRebWDzMkc , but with -O2 and on my machine with any optimisation **normalMethod()** runs way faster. I do understand your idea, but I don't know what's going on, I might have messed up something, idk